# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have two tables, one for users and one for the new items. I have reference for the id in the users table in the items table.

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('item_title');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('items', function($table) {
             $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
```

This is my controller for adding new item

```
public function storeItem(Request $request){
        $user = Auth::user();

        $item = new Item([
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'item_title' => $request->input('title'),
        ]);

        $item->save();    
    }
```

But when I submit the form I have this error `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`database`.`items`, CONSTRAINT`items_user_id_foreign`FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES`users`(`id`))`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, firstly try to fix up your migrations:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('restrict');
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('items');
}
```

run `$ php artisan migrate:refresh`

> **Note**: using prefix "item_" is looking bad, you already have table named as **item(s)**, so drop the prefix... name your columns properly

**controller (method)**

```
public function storeItem(Request $request, App\Item $item) 
{
    $user = $request->user(); // get current user making the request

    $data = array_merge($request->only(['title']), ['user_id' => $user->id]);
    $newItem = $item->create($data);
    //$newItem has instance of your created item
}
```

> **Note**: remember to correctly fill `$fillable` array in your Item model (in this case it should have only `'title'` and `'user_id'`)

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo, it should be:

```
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
```

Comment: I edit that, it was mistake, but thats not the error, I have that error again

Comment: Well you've copy-pasted wrong code, so I guess you ran `migrate` command with it. Did you run `migrate:refresh` or `migrate:rollback` command after you fixed this? If yes, did you get any error messages?

Comment: Yes yes, i migrate that again and nothing has changed, do i have to make some relationship function?

Answer (score -1):

Try this code,
    $user = Auth::user();
    $item = new Item([
        'item_title' => $request->input('title')
    ]);
    $item->user()->add($user);
    $item->save();

You have to define a user relationship in Item model.

Comment: I have this error now `BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2448:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::add()`

Answer (score -1):

in you item model write below code:

```
protected $table = 'items';
protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'title'];
```

then try